# If $f(x) \to 0$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

let $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be continuous such that $f(x) \to 0$ as $\|x\| \to \infty$. how do I prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R^n$?

ok I saw a question here where $n = 1$ and i think it is the same idea but there is one thing i don't understand

let $\epsilon >0$ then there exists $M >0$ such that if $\|x\| > M$ then $|f(x)| < \epsilon/2$. and because the closed ball $B'(0,M)$ is compact $f$ is uniformly continuous there so there exist $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ if $\|x - y\| < \delta$

also if $|x| > M$ and $|y| > M$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| \le |f(x)| + |f(y)| < \epsilon$

QUESTION:

what if $|x| > M$ and $|y| \le M$?

thanks for help

Comment: Intruduce a $z$ such that $|z|=M$ and consider $ |f(x) - f(y)|\leq |f(x) - f(z)| + |f(z) -f(y)|  $.

Comment: @guestDiego i like this idea! so then I choose as my compact $B'(0,M+1)$ to make sure $|f(z)| < \epsilon/2$ then i use uniform continuity on it for |f(z) - f(y)|. right?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Actually I wrote the answer suggested by Joanpemo (but with $M+1$). It is not exactly what you asked me, but it is a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. 
There exists $M_\epsilon$ such that
$$
|z|\geq M_\epsilon\Rightarrow |f(z)|\leq \epsilon/2.
$$
In particular,
$$
|x|\geq M_\epsilon\,\wedge\,|y| \geq M_\epsilon \Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon
$$
Moreover, by the uniform continuity on $\overline{B(0,M_\epsilon+1)}$, there exists $1>\delta_\epsilon>0$ such that
$$
\forall x,y\in \overline{B(0,M_\epsilon+1)}\quad |x-y|\leq \delta_\epsilon\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon.
$$
This cover all cases. In fact, if $|x-y|\leq\delta_\epsilon<1$, then either $|x|,|y|\geq M_\epsilon $ or $|x|,|y|\leq M_\epsilon +1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\|f(x)\|\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact set $K_\varepsilon$ such that $\|f(x)\|<\varepsilon$ outside $K_\epsilon$. So $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous over $K_\varepsilon$, since $f$ is a continuous function and $K_\varepsilon$ is a compact set, while outside $K_\varepsilon$ we have $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq 2\varepsilon$ by the triangle inequality.

Comment: thanks but i'm not sure this answers my question

Comment: @madmatician: It does.  Take $\varepsilon>0$ and consider $K_{\epsilon/2}$. By the uniform continuity over $K_{\epsilon/2}$, there is a $\delta$ such that $\|x-y\|\leq \delta$ ensures $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq \varepsilon/2$ for $x,y\in K_{\epsilon/2}$. So $\|x-y\|\leq\delta$ ensures $\|f(x)-f(y)\|\leq\varepsilon$ without further assumptions.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think the asker's question was how to be sure both the norms of $\;x,y\;$ are on the same side of $\;M\;$ whenever $\;|x-y|<\delta\;$

Answer (score 0):

It will always be possible to choose $\;\delta>0\;$ so that **both** $\;x,\,y\;$ fulfill $\;|x|,\,|y|\le M\;$ or both $\;|x|,\,|y|>M\;$ whenever $\;\left\|x-y\right\|<\delta\;$ . Can you see how?

Comment: ok now i get it. thanks